# How can I compile CIL code that is Large Address Aware

Tags: .net-assembly, cil, compiler-flags

I have compiled a c# application and dll for "Any CPU" and decompiled both afterwards with ildasm.exe. In the next step I assembled the data (.il and .res) file back into an application/dll file with ilasm.exe which worked fine, except for the Large Address Aware flag.

When looking into the .il file, the COFF Header Characteristics `0x2122`  indicate that the Large Address Aware flag was detected, but the re-assembled file is lacking this flag `0x2102`.

Disassembler command:
`ildasm.exe "test.dll" /out="test.il" /text /all /bytes /linenum /nobar /source /tokens`

Assembler commands:
`ilasm.exe "test.il" /out="test.il.dll" /res:"test.res" /dll /optimize /flags=0x2122`

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: These are the not the /flags you meant to use, 0x2122 is not a correct value.  Options like /highentropyva set the DLL characteristics.  But there isn't one for LAA, you need to use editbin.exe afterwards to turn it on.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans Passant for your fast and precise help with both, the /flag meaning and how to set the LAA flag.